Android Studio Flutter How to organize editor code like a nested tree
I'm using Flutter in Android studio. I can't find a way to organize the code in editor such a way that shows subcategory of each code block as a nest. It is very helpful visually since widgets are the building blocks here and I get confused without the nested tree guides. Below is the example of what I need to find (you see the 90 degree L type lines).


To organize the code, press Ctrl + Alt + L in Windows.
And if you want nested tree guides, go to File\Settings\Appearance and scroll and find UI Options, in Options. You can check Show tree indent guides.

Can you tell me what happening?

show tree indent guide is active. The horizontal nested lines are not shown
